# Why is everything in Form.resx automatically cleaned after saving Form.designer.cs in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

It is my first time to use resx file to store strings in Visual Studio. It's so weird that when I modified something on designer.cs, and saved it, all strings in resx were gone. Does anyone meet this issue before? How to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: You should put your custom strings (ie not directly related to controls) in separate .resx files from your designer ones.

Comment: If so, what does Form.resx do? When should I use it?

Comment: Take a look at [Localizing a Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28VS.80%29.aspx). Those .resx files are specifically designed to contain your controls' translations, so anything else put inside will be removed by the Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not edit `Form.resx` files manually. Together with `Form.Designer.cs` files they should only be edited with the use of winform designer.

`Form.resx` and `Form.locale.resx` files contains all resources associated with that form controls: icons, cursors, images, localization strings, etc.

If you need to put custom resources, then simply create separate resx-files (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx) of how to work with them).

It is still a question, if you really need to use resource files. Having `static` class to store strings is much more comfortable way, you will have all power of intellisence (find all references, no spelling errors, etc), while accessing resources required specifying identificator, where you can very easily make a mistake or two. If you think about localization, then it's different story (but still, you can use reflection and text-files to have it way more comfortable then microsoft satellite way).

Answer (score 0):

Form.resx is only used by WinForms designer, so leave it alone in all cases.

The contents stored in such designer managed resource files can be,

- Form icons
- Control tooltips if their contents are longer than a predefined length
- `ImageList` contents
- and many other (which is undocumented)

Like @Kilazur pointed out, you should store your own resources in newly created resource files that are not controlled by the designer.